# Difference in noise levels between inverting and non-inverting inputs of LM386

Tags: noise, lm386

An [article on Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/2016/12/07/you-can-have-my-lm386s-when-you-pry-them-from-my-cold-dead-hands/) claims that the inverting input of LM386 is less noisy than the non-inverting one:

> We’ve also noticed, and we’re not alone, that the inverting input seems to be less noisy than the non-inverting. See how the datasheet applications ground the inverting input (pin 2) and put the signal into pin 3? Do exactly the opposite and you’ll reduce your noise floor even further.

I'm wondering if this is really true, and if so, is this a peculiarity of this particular chip or manifestation of some more general rule?

My understanding of electronics does not allow me to draw any conclusions from the equivalent schematics provided in [TI's LM386 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) :
[image: LM386 internal schematic]

Does it sound plausible? Is there a way to measure this in 'home conditions' (i.e. without expensive equipment, oscilloscope and multimeter only?)

Comment: When using the non-inverting input, the voltage gain is slightly higher than when using the inverting input connected to a signal source hence, there will be slightly more noise because there's more signal gain. The Hackaday article has no credentials as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Andyaka: This could be a full answer too. Thanks!

Comment: You've already closed the question down so, not by my hand! But feel free to make an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signal to noise ratio at the output of an amplifier circuit depends on:

1. The noise figure of the chip (stated in the datasheet at a given bias point)
2. External network (designer needs) which fixes the gain
3. Temperature

To answer your question:

One can't say that that the inverting input is less noisy.
It depends on the bias point of the chip and on the voltage gain.